# Pointwise convergence of $h_{n}(x)=x^{1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}$

Tags: real-analysis

The following statement appeared in my textbook:

> Consider $h_{n}(x)=x^{1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}$ on the set $[-1, 1]$, for a
>    fixed $x \in [-1, 1]$, we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} h_n(x) =
>  |x|$.

Can someone explain why $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} h_{n}(x) = |x|$? Specifically, where did the absolute value sign come from? What limit laws/rules are used to obtain this result?

I would have thought $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} h_n(x) = x \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^{\frac{1}{2n-1}} = x$?

EDIT: I had a look at the other question suggested, but my question is different because I want to know the exact limit laws used in each step of the justification that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} h_n(x) =
 |x|$.

Comment: Mention the textbook and page number where this appeared.

Comment: @SahibaArora Understanding Analysis by Abbot, Chapter 6. Sequences and Series of Functions, example 6.2.2 (iii)